# Serilog: Is it okay to cache LogEventProperty produced by ILogEventPropertyFactory?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I am implementing my own `ILogEventEnricher`:

```
public interface ILogEventEnricher
{
    void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory);
}
```

And I wonder will it be idiomatic to store `LogEventProperty` object created by `ILogEventPropertyFactory` so that I could reuse this property during futher enrichments? Because I do not like the idea of re-serializing my context properties every logging call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LogEventProperty` created by `ILogEventPropertyFactory` is essentially a pair of property name and value. Value has a type of abstract `LogEventPropertyValue` class that has concrete descendants like `ScalarValue`, `StructureValue`, `SequenceValue`, etc. Each of these classes just keeps original property value (preprocessed in some way) and dumps it with pretty formatting in `Render()` method.

As you see `LogEventProperty` is basically a data bag with no magic behind it. If you call `ILogEventPropertyFactory.CreateProperty()` several times for the same property names and values, you will get equal `LogEventProperty` objects that will produce the same data in the log.

So yes, it's ok to cache `LogEventProperty` instances for performance considerations.